# Microsoft Speech Recognition Custom Training

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech, sapi

I have been wanting to create an application using the Microsoft Speech Recognition.

My application's users are expected to often say abbreviated things, such as 'LHC' for 'Large Hadron Collider' or 'CERN'. Given that exact order, my application will return

> You said: At age C.
>
> You said: Cern

While it did work for 'CERN', it failed very badly for 'LHC'.

However, if I could make my own custom training files, I could easily place the term 'LHC' somewhere in there. Then, I could make the user access the Speech Control Panel and run my training file.

All the links I have found for this have been frustratingly useless, as they just say things like 'This is ----, you should try going to the ---- forum instead'.

If it does help, here is a list of the links:

http://compgroups.net/comp.speech.users/add-my-own-training/153194

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.speech.server/v58SH1ov22s

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/servercorefordevelopers/thread/f7a35f3f-b352-464a-b264-e16eb4afd049

Is my problem even possible? Or are the training files themselves in a special format? If so, can that format be reproduced?

A solution that can also work on Windows XP would be ideal.

Thanks in advance!

P.S. If there are any libraries or modules out there already for this, could anyone point me to some? A Python or C/C++ solution would be splendid. Also, since I'd rather not post another question regarding this, is it possible to utilize the train utilities from command prompt (or without the GUI visible, but still having total command of all controls)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, pulling this from a thing I [wrote three or four years ago](http://blog.thomascsherman.com/2009/08/getting-started-with-windows-voice-recognition/) now, but I believe you want to do something like this.

The grammar library is a trained system which can recognize words. You can create your own grammar library cued to specific words.

C#, sorry

```
using System.Speech
using System.Speech.Recognition
using System.Speech.AudioFormat

SpeechRecognitionEngine sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();

string[] words = {"L H C", "CERN"};
Choices choices = new Choices(words);
GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder(choices);
Grammar grammar = new Grammar(gb);
sre.LoadGrammar(grammar);
```

That is as far as I can get you. From docs it looks like you can define the pronunciations somehow. So perhaps that way you could have LHC map directly to a single word. Here are the docs on the grammar class - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.grammar.aspx

Small update - see example in their docs here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms554228.aspx

Comment: C# is great! So if I add 'L H C' into the grammar, it will be able to recognize it next time? Without having to have the user say the word? Also, if I call LoadGrammar(), does it SAVE the grammar for the next time I run it? Say I have a C# app that sets the grammar, and then a Python program use the MSSR, the grammar would work? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Nox - The first question, yes, I believe it will recognize LHC like ELL, ACH, CEE. You might have to spell them phonetically though like, ell, ashe, see or something. Not sure whether the system recognizes letters as words. For second part, I have no idea. :/

Comment: Thanks! It worked! Sorry for the late response: I wasn't able to log in for a while.